# How recurrent neural network work when predict many days?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks

I use recurrent neural network, RNNs have to get input one value per step and it will show one value output. If I have daily sale demand time series data.

I want to predict sale demand for three days. So, Rnn have to show output one day in three time or it can show sale  demand three days output in one time prediction ?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicated question concerning  "time-series" ,Have you tried to query through the knowledge base? However,we are here to do help for the good of human civilisation, so I kindly request you to go through the community guidelines for effective feedback  besides future benefits.So let's cooperate and be nice.